# WPF: Global resource accessible by key

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, styles

I'm styling the Grid controls to be the table headers using resources like so:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,10" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundDarkBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.0,1.0,0.0,0" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundDarkBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundLightBrush}" />
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

The thing is, I need to apply that resources into multiple places in my app, which leads to the code being repeated.

I was wondering if this is possible to store the resources in my `App.xaml` and use them by the key or something like that? Like so:

```
<Resources Key="MyResourceSet">
     <Style>
         [..]
     </Style>
</Resources>

<Grid Resource="MyResourceSet">
[...]
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried it? You absolutely can.  When looking for a resource it starts at the first available resource and looks upwards so App.xaml is the last place it looks for the resource.  Example... TextBlock, Button, Grid, Window, App... If using the resource in the TextBlock it will look for it there first and outward like so as example.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII I can't use them by key/name. This is not possible.

Comment: It is possible, I do it all the time.

Comment: I believe you may be asking something differently now that I'm scratching my head about it.  You want to apply a resource dictionary to your individual controls.  You can do this also but not how you're expecting I don't believe.

Comment: Yeah. I think you misunderstood my point. What I want is, for example, `<Resources Key="MyResourceSet">` to only apply to the controls within `<Grid Resource="MyResourceSet">`. I could of course separate each style and use by the `{StaticResource key}`, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Apologies... I've updated my answer with an alternative to what you're asking that may fit the bill.  It's about the same.  Please see the bottom half of it and let me know if that helps.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Thank you so much for your effort! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the Style in the App.Resources like you would in any other UIElement.

```
<Application x:Class="Question_Answer_WPF_App.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle"
               TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Green" />
            <Setter Property="Height"
                    Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="Width"
                    Value="100" />
        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Reference wherever you want in your app.

```
<Window x:Class="Question_Answer_WPF_App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">

    <Button Content="Testing"
            Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" />

</Window>
```

[image]

### Another way to do this if you want several `ResourceDictionary's` to be used across your app; but with the same inner keys, is to reference the unique `ResourceDictionary` per element that will use it.  This will not be using the `App.xaml` resources but will be pointing directly to the file location in your application. Since `ResourceDictionary's` have a default 'Build Action' of 'Page' it will work referencing the location this way.  If your `ResourceDictionary` doesn't work this way the first thing is to check this by right clicking the `ResourceDictionary` in your solution explorer and make sure that's correct.

**Example:**

**MyCustomResourcesA.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
                Value="46" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle"
           TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Green" />
        <Setter Property="Height"
                Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="Width"
                Value="100" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MyCustomResourcesB.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Question_Answer_WPF_App">

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
                Value="26" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle"
           TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Blue" />
        <Setter Property="Height"
                Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Width"
                Value="200" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Question_Answer_WPF_App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">

        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="MyCustomResourcesA.xaml" />
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <TextBlock Text="I'm using MyCustomResourcesA" />
            <Button Content="Testing"
                    Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="MyCustomResourcesB.xaml" />
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <TextBlock Text="I'm using MyCustomResourcesB" />
            <Button Content="Testing"
                    Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thats what I was looking for! :-) Thanks

Comment: @Rusco NP, apologies on the initial confusion.